# Apply inner and outer box-shadow to a single HTML element

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to apply 2 box-shadows to a HTML element at once? I am trying to apply both an inner(inset) & outer box shadow.

This gives the effect a blurred inside of the element & then just a normal outer shadow.

For eg:

```
box-shadow: inset 5px 5px #000000;
box-shadow: -1px 5px #FF00FF;
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Yes.

You can simply do something like:

```
box-shadow: 0 0 5px #FF00FF, inset 0 0 5px #000000;
```

[A working example.](http://jsfiddle.net/joshsmith/JGaqG/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
box-shadow: inset 5px 5px #000000, -1px 5px #FF00FF;
```